# React + Redux as Static Site: limitations?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

I'm going to build React + Redux + Webpack app. And I think about building it as static site which I could put on hosting (like S3).

Are there any limitations or some serious disadvantages to deploy React+Redux+Webpack app to hosting as static site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing. React-Redux-Webpack, for my opinion, the best platform to perform static web-app with dynamic UI. You can compile your app with webpack like [in this starter kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit). Your app will be as easy to minfiy, compile, test and deploy as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

There are no disadvantages to build React+Redux+Webpack based web-app. But I would feel it is better to use only React+Webpack and maintain state in component state locally. Using Redux in case of static web apps might become a overhead.

Comment: Your code might become spaghetti if you wont to build some complex architecture for your ui and you will manage state only locally

Comment: I agree for complex architecture its better to use Redux. But if ui state transition is less(which is true in case of some static apps) then managing local state is much easier. Basically it all depends on how complex the app is.